# Facebook like button internet explorer confirm issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm building a Facebook app, on which I want to use a 'Like' button. When I click the Like button, I have to confirm that I want to like the specified page. I understand that this is because of anti-spam and that it automatically will disappear etc. I'm using an FB.Event.Subscribe event on the Like button, because I want to do an action when the user clicks the button. All this works well on Chrome and Firefox. But on Internet Explorer if I test the app, when clicked on the Like button, and after that on confirm, my like isn't registered, and the FB.Event.Subscribe event not triggered. Does anybody know why, and even better, does someone have a solution or work-around?

Thanks!

Comment: What verison of IE are you testing with?

Comment: @MobileFire I'm testing with IE11

Comment: And I'm testing the app itself, so the http://apps.facebook.com/myapp url. On my own domain, it works well, also with IE11

Answer (score 0):

*Liking a comment requires the publish_stream permission...*

Like a comment: issue a POST to [https://graph.facebook.com/[COMMENT](https://graph.facebook.com/%5bCOMMENT) ID]/likes 
Delete a like: issue a DELETE to [https://graph.facebook.com/[COMMENT](https://graph.facebook.com/%5bCOMMENT) ID]/likes

curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_475058873552_14173716/likes

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish vs the issue. Maybe your code would help.

Here's an example of a callback that can handle either the edge.create or edge.remove event:

```
var page_like_or_unlike_callback = function(url, html_element) {
  console.log("page_like_or_unlike_callback");
  console.log(url);
  console.log(html_element);
}

// In your onload handler
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', page_like_or_unlike_callback);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to like a comment, but a page. I use the FB.Event.Subscribe exact the same way as you. Even if I dont use the event, my like isn't registered